# How to perform self join with same row of previous group(month) to bring in additional columns in Pyspark

Tags: python, dataframe, hive, pyspark

In continuation to the stackoverflow question as it din't have properly explained about the issue: [How to perform self join with same row of previous group(month) to bring in additional columns with different expressions in Pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62957917/how-to-perform-self-join-with-same-row-of-previous-groupmonth-to-bring-in-addi)  (for better explanation)

Based on the below input I have to derive the output (shown) as per the formula added in the last column of output data for explanation. Here basically, I need to create new opt 1 ....n columns based on the value 1 ....n columns from Input.

**Input:**

```
|Month_no|value1 |value2 |
|  01    |10     |20     |
|  01    |20     |30     |
|  02    |30     |40     |
|  02    |40     |50     |
|  03    |50     |60     |
|  03    |60     |70     |
|  04    |70     |80     |
|  04    |80     |90     |
```

Output:

```
|Month_no|value1 |value2 |opt1   |opt2  |formula(just for explanation) to calculate opt1 an opt 2
|  01    |10     |20     |10     |20    |same as value 1 or value 2 for 01
|  01    |20     |30     |20     |30    |same as value 1 or value 2 for 01
|  02    |30     |40     |40     |60    |add 02 value 1 or value 2 + previous month 01 opt1 or opt 2 value
|  02    |40     |50     |60     |80    |add 02 value 1 or value 2 + previous month 01 opt1 or opt 2 value
|  03    |50     |60     |90     |120   |add 03 value 1 or value 2 + previous month 02 opt1 or opt 2 value
|  03    |60     |70     |120    |150   |add 03 value 1 or value 2 + previous month 02 opt1 or opt 2 value
|  04    |70     |80     |70     |80    |same as value 1 or value 2 for 04
|  04    |80     |90     |80     |90    |same as value 1 or value 2 for 04
```

My way of code:

Get the list of distinct monthno# id from thr input dataframe.

```
month_list = sorted([row['Month_no'] for row in df.select(df.Month_no).distint().collect()])
```

using a for loop, iterating over the month_list variable

```
for date in month_list:
  if date is in 01 or 04 or 07 or 10:
     # Iterating on the value columns and creating the new opt1...n columns as same as value1....n values
  else:
     Filter the data for the current iteration
     df_present = df.filter(df.Month_no == "02")
     df_previous = df.filter(df.Month_no == "01")  # present month - 1
     # doing left join considering the value1...n columns from df_present and opt1...n columns (renamed clmn) from df_previous data to calculate the addition.
     df_joined = df_present.join(df_previous, on="key_column", left).select(df_present.columns, df_prevous_renamed_columns.columns)
```

In the same way the iterating the loop and union the data, so that previous month calculated new columns will be useful for the current month iteration. Then the final unioned dataframe is returned.

But, being use of for loop consumes more time in calculating data for huge no# of records. Request that we can get into any other approach or not??

Comment: Do you have a column which allows us to sort the dataframe (maybe `value1`)?

Comment: @cronoik, ya we can do.

Answer (score 0):

Something you could work with is the [lag](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.lag) window function which allows you to access a row before your current row:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window

l = [( '01'    ,10     ,20     )
,(  '01'   ,20     ,30     )
,(  '02'    ,30     ,40     )
,(  '02'    ,40     ,50     )
,(  '03'    ,50     ,60     )
,(  '03'    ,60     ,70     )
,(  '04'    ,70     ,80     )
,(  '04'    ,80     ,90    )]

df = spark.createDataFrame(l, ['Month_no','value1', 'value2' ])

df = df.withColumn('opt1', df.value1)
df = df.withColumn('opt2', df.value2)    

w = Window.orderBy('value1')
    
#We use lag(COLUMN, 2) to get the row before the previous row
calculationRequiredMonthsE = ['02', '05', '08', '11']
calculationRequiredMonthsU = ['03', '06', '09', '12']

df = df.withColumn('opt1', F.when(F.col('Month_no').isin(calculationRequiredMonthsE), F.col('opt1') + F.lag('opt1', 2).over(w)).otherwise(F.col('opt1')))
df = df.withColumn('opt2', F.when(F.col('Month_no').isin(calculationRequiredMonthsE), F.col('opt2') + F.lag('opt2', 2).over(w)).otherwise(F.col('opt2')))
df = df.withColumn('opt1', F.when(F.col('Month_no').isin(calculationRequiredMonthsU), F.col('opt1') + F.lag('opt1', 2).over(w)).otherwise(F.col('opt1')))
df = df.withColumn('opt2', F.when(F.col('Month_no').isin(calculationRequiredMonthsU), F.col('opt2') + F.lag('opt2', 2).over(w)).otherwise(F.col('opt2')))

df.show()
```

Output:

```
+--------+------+------+----+----+
|Month_no|value1|value2|opt1|opt2|
+--------+------+------+----+----+
|      01|    10|    20|  10|  20|
|      01|    20|    30|  20|  30|
|      02|    30|    40|  40|  60|
|      02|    40|    50|  60|  80|
|      03|    50|    60|  90| 120|
|      03|    60|    70| 120| 150|
|      04|    70|    80|  70|  80|
|      04|    80|    90|  80|  90|
+--------+------+------+----+----+
```

Please keep in mind that a Window without [partitionBy](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Window.partitionBy) can cause performance issues. In case you have another column which allows partitioning (e.g. year), you should always use it.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation with a proper spark lines. I understood the way of doing. But, I could see using a for loop may cause problem in sequential process. Even I have a method tested with for loop and its not having good performance benifit. Please suggest?

Comment: @Rocky1989 I have removed the loop to reduce the execution plan.